# Proper way to set up python TimerTrigger in Azure Functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I have a TimerTrigger Azure Function (running in a Docker container) that I can't get to work. The `__init__.py` executes, pulls in some custom modules, scrapes the interwebs (with selenium), and outputs to Twitter. Locally all the code works. When packaged into an Azure Function Docker container, locally, I get zilch.

Below, I've put the `function.json` file, which I think is where my issue lies. I think I might need some more components here, beyond just the TimerTrigger part. There's not great documentation on the internet for python-based Azure Functions & TimerTriggers, beyond what Microsoft has put out (and believe me, I've thoroughly read each of those articles).

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 * * * * *",
      "authLevel": "anonymous"
    }
  ]
}
```

Beginning of my `__init__.py` (I basically put all my custom modules, etc. within the function automatically created when initiated the function):

```
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None: #should be something else?
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
    
    # Class instantiation for the handling stuff ----
    name_handle_instance = dc.NameHandle()
    #calls other functions below...
```

If the Dockerfile would be pertinent:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.6-appservice

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

# install python dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        wget \
        unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools    

# chrome install
ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

# install chromedriver used by Selenium
RUN LATEST=$(wget -q -O - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && \
    wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && ln -s /chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver:${PATH}"

RUN pip install -U selenium
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: "schedule": "0 * * * * *" what does this indicates? you want to run every hour?

Comment: Every minute, for testing purposes. Would change it to a few times a day, once everything works

Comment: should not that be like this? 0 */1 * * * *?

Comment: Got it from here: https://www.shanebart.com/azure-cron-cheat-sheet/

Comment: yeah if its every minute, it should be 1 not 0

Comment: Made that specific change, and works locally, without building the container. But still lost on getting it working within the container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231997/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-papelr).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Function code is absolutely correct. As you said, locally all the code works. You didn't mention how you deploy to container in your question.

**The problem is in this step:** push to Docker container. See this article: [Docker Container on Azure Functions with Python](https://dev.to/omer95/docker-container-on-azure-functions-with-python-1lgd)

About how to config Dokerfiles, see this [Python in a container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python)

Comment: Ok awesome, will dig into the articles. I added my Dockerfile above, if that would be helpful. I've been building my image locally (basically this: `docker build --tag <YOUR_DOCKER_HUBB_ID>/ocrfunctionsimage:v1.0.0 .`) and then running it locally in a container. I get no action on the trigger when I do that